# D3 v5: d3.nest() is unsuccessful

Tags: d3.js

Huge thank you in advance, I am new to D3. I am trying to make a multiline chart, I have a single line chart coded up that I am trying to transition to a multiline chart. I have data that looks like:

```
country,year,average
United States,1972,54
United States,1973,56
United States,1974,53
United States,1975,57
United States,1976,60
Brazil,1972,24
Brazil,1973,21
Brazil,1974,25
Brazil,1975,26
Brazil,1976,24
South Africa,1972,17
South Africa,1973,18
South Africa,1974,19
South Africa,1975,21
South Africa,1976,25
```

This data goes on to include other countries. What I would like to do is nest this by country in order to create a line for each country.

My code:

```
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y"); 

function rowConverter(data) {
    return {
        country : data.country, 
        year : parseTime(data.year),
        average : +data.average // the + operator parses strings into numbers
    };
d3.csv("EvenMore.csv", rowConverter, function(data) {

    var countries = d3.nest()
        .key(function (d) { return d.country; })
        .entries(data); 

    console.log(countries);
```

The console looks like:

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HYt0.png)

Comment: What version of D3 are you using?

Comment: @altocumulus v5

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate; your way of loading via `d3.csv()` is not correct for v5. The third argument, i.e. you data handler callback, is now interpreted as being the row conversion function which is the reason why your code does not work. Trying following the advice in the dupe target.

Comment: `d3.csv("EvenMore.csv", rowConverter).then(function(data) { /*...*/ });` will do.